# Check if Named Range is equal to another Named Range

Tags: excel, vb.net, if-statement, named-ranges

I’m trying to resize a Named Range in Excel if the Named Range “InventoryList” is equal to the Named Range passed into the Sub. I can’t seem to get the correct syntax for this. The "IF" statement is where I'm getting the error. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub Resize_Inventory_Range(InventoryList As Excel.Range)

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim FullInventory As Excel.Range

        xlApp = GetObject(, Constants.ExcelApp)
        WB = xlApp.Workbooks("Product")
        WS = WB.Sheets("Inventory")
        FullInventory = WS.Range("Full_Inventory")

        If InventoryList.Name.Name = "Hardware_Inventory" Then
            FullInventory.Resize(FullInventory.Rows.Count + 1, 4).Name = FullInventory.Name.Name
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual value of InventoryList.Name.Name?  Remembering string comparisons with the "=" are case  sensative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the two ranges are the same by comparing their addresses. For example:

```
MsgBox InventoryList.Address = FullInventory.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

What `name.name` returns depends on wether the name is defined on workbook- or on worksheet-level. In case of worksheet level name will return e.g. "Table1!Hardware_Inventory".

So your check should be:

`If InventoryList.Name.Name like "*Hardware_Inventory" Then`

(In case there could be a name "Old_Hardware_Inventory" you would have to built a more complex check ...)

And to be on the safe side - in case the supplied range has no name - you should use this function instead. Checking for the name always returns an error when there is no name.

```
Public Function tryGetName(c As Range) As String
'if range has no name this will catch the error
'an empty string is returned
On Error Resume Next
tryGetName = c.Name.Name
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This is one of the rare occasions where I think `on error resume next` is ok.

Your check would then look like:

`If tryGetName(InventoryList) like "*Hardware_Inventory" Then`